# Is Twitter's Bootstrap toolkit ready for production use?

Tags: css, twitter, less, twitter-bootstrap

While most modern browsers are claimed to be supported by the toolkit, is Twitter's Bootstrap toolkit ready for production use? Has anyone used it thoroughly enough to know if it works properly on all the browsers listed on the website? [twitter bootstrap homepage](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

Comment: "Has anyone used it thoroughly enough to know if it works properly on all the browsers listed on the website?" Uhhh... Twitter?

Comment: Wrong. Twitter doesn't use it.

Answer (score 6):

It's a CSS framework, and it seems to be fairly resilient - a lot of people are using it, and there's a showcase of sites here: http://builtwithbootstrap.tumblr.com/

That being said, YMMV and it's always best to do your own testing.

Chances are you'll style over it with your own styling to help customise it as well, so that will affect how it works.

I've tested it with a few browsers for basic products and it has worked pretty well out of the box, but there are parts like the gradients that work nicer in Chrome, etc, and less exciting in older IE, and there is no real mobile css in there and won't be until version 2.0.

That being said, I have viewed it on an ipad, iphone and android phone and it's readable, if not custom for mobile devices out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple CSS framework. I don't see any problems why you shouldn't use it on a productive site.

Comment: Just saying hi. Isn't this where we say that we aren't completely impartial?

Answer (score 0):

I've used in two massive projects, and it worked great.